# How to export symbols from modules compiled by Closure Compiler?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, google-closure-compiler, google-closure-library, es6-modules

I have many js es6 modules compiled by Closure Compiler (Advanced level) in a single library file.

I failed to export some symbols using `/** @export */` or using `goog.exportSymbol('whatever', whatever)` to uncompiled javascript in HTML pages .

How to do it?

Remarque: If I replace the es6 `import`/`export` by `goog.require`/`goog.provide` in all modules, it works and I can successfully use these symbols in HTML pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further investigations, I found the solution.

Although loaded in the browser without any error in the console (except `undefined whatever` of course), my library was not executed. I simply moved the closure library ahead of the file stack to be compiled and my library was then properly executed by the browser with my symbols properly exported.

The 3 ways to export symbols are working in compiled es6 modules: `/** @export */ whatever`, `goog.exportSymbol('whatever', whatever)`, `window['whatever'] = whatever`. The first 2 being a handy way for the third one.

Fort more details see [No exported symbols with es6 modules library compiled by Closure Compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46092308/no-exported-symbols-with-es6-modules-library-compiled-by-closure-compiler/46362739#46362739)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `@export` in a module, but `goog.exportSymbol` should work. Your other option is to manually export them:

```
window['whatever'] = whatever;
```

Comment: Neither `goog.exportSymbol` nor `window['whatever'] = whatever` work for me: When I put `Object.keys( window )` in the browser console, I can see only the obfuscated symbols (The same code generates properly unobfuscated symbols when using `goog.require`/`goog.provide` instead of es6 `import`/`export`).

Comment: That means something else is going on. You'll have to post a complete minimal reproduction case of the issue.